# Valid email address in JavaScript using RegularExpression

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have to valid email address in JavaScript. My method is

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

    return re.test(email);
}
```

Issue is that Visual Studio is not accepting the Regular Expression and giving error when i run the application. The error is [image]

Comment: No, its javascript and i am using it in .cshtml file of ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Is it within a script tag?

Comment: Yes, it is within the script tag @evolutionxbox

Comment: Should JS inside a cshtml file be in a string? Otherwise it might be confused for c#.

Comment: @evolutionxbox have a look at Alex answer

Comment: Related: [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1364007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping `@`. `@@` will render as `@`

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^\w+([.]\w+)*@\w+([.]\w+)+$
```